# Iterating over implementations of an Interface in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to iterate over an implementation of an interface in Angular 2 with *ngFor?

My desired use is shown below.

**TypeScript Example:**

```
export interface Animal
{
  name: string;
  vertebrate: boolean;
}

export class Bird implements Animal
{
  name: string;
  vertebrate: boolean;
  wingSpan: number;
}

export class Fish implements Animal
{
  name: string;
  vertebrate: boolean;
  color: string;
}

<!--Where earth would be an object with Animals: Animal[];-->

<div *ngFor="let animal of earth.Animals">

    <span *ngIf="animal.vertebrate">{{animal.name}}</span>

    <span *ngIf="animal.getType == 'Bird' ">{{animal.wingSpan}}</span>

</div>
```

What is shown above is a simplified example of the project I'm working on.

In my project while trying to iterate over implementations of an interface everything compiles and there are no errors. However, nothing shows on the page.

Any advice is appreciated on how to approach this problem **iterating over implementations of an interface**.

Comment: Can you show the `earth` object? And can you please update you post to show your correct use of `*ngIf`, since you said it was a typo, and please fix any other typos you may have

Comment: @peeskillet I fixed for the correct use of *ngIf.

Comment: Just FYI, the interface is not the problem. All typing is erased at runtime. All that matters is the contents of the object. That's why I asked you to show your `earth` object

Comment: @peeskillet the earth object is hypothetical. All I want to know is if it is possible to iterate through different implementations (Birds & Fishes) of an interface (Animal) with one *ngFor loop.

Comment: Sure you can...

Comment: @peeskillet Okay thanks for the advice, that other comment was to the original response, hadn't seen your new replies